# Get browser.element into page objects with children

Tags: javascript, prototype, protractor

I am doing testing when I fork a driver instance to send messages between browsers. I also use page objects for mapping the view. In my page objects I have other page objects, some of who inherits from another page object. Though, when I have forked a driver instance and have two browsers to work with, it's troublesome to get the **element** function from the forked driver in the page objects. Especially for the page object who other PO inherits from. This is a sample from my code:

```
var NavBar = function () {  
    this.button = element(by.buttonText('Click'));
};

var MySiteElement = function () {
    this.someElement = element(by.name('hiddenElement'));
};

NavBar.prototype = new MySiteElement();

var HomeView = function (element) {
    this.navbar = new NavBar()
};

module.exports = HomeView;
```

Let's say my spec looks like this:

```
describe('Home View', funciton () {
    it('should get text from right browser', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/#/home');
        var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
        var view = new HomeView(browser.element);
        var view2 = new HomeView(browser2.element);
        view2.navbar.content.click()
        expect(view.navbar.someElement.getText()).toBe('unchanged')
        expect(view2.navbar.someElement.getText()).toBe('changed')
    });
});
```

Let's say that my site is composed so that when the navbar button is clicked, the someElement's text change to 'changed'. But I have to click on the right element, and it's not right to use just element when I have a forked browser that I want to interact with. But I don't know how to set the right element variable inside the HomeView page object. I now that browser2.element get me the element variable from the forked driver, but how do I expose that to all the page object. Currently I pass the browser instance's element property as an argument to the page object, but I don't know how to go further.

Please help, this has got me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution. Since the element function only should be passed once (when instantiating the HomeView since every other PO is a child of the HomeView) I only pass the element function once. All declarations of the classes are then nested inside the HomeView object function:

```
var HomeView = function (element) {
    var NavBar = function () {  
        this.button = element(by.buttonText('Click'));
    };

    var MySiteElement = function () {
        this.someElement = element(by.name('hiddenElement'));
    };

    NavBar.prototype = new MySiteElement();

    this.navbar = new NavBar(element);
};

module.exports = HomeView;
```

However, if you have several View objects, this means repeating yourself (no good). I use node modules for importing the page objects, and the modules' scope don't inherit from where they're required. But to this I have a solution as well. In the module where the page object lies, export a function holding the page object declaration and pass the element to it.

```
var HomeView = function (element) {
    var NavBar = require('./navBar.po.js')(element):

    this.navbar = new NavBar();
};

module.exports = HomeView
```

And `./navBar.po.js` would look like this:

```
module.exports = function (element) {
    require('./mySiteElement.po.js')(element);

    var NavBar = function () {
        this.button = element(by.buttonText('Click'));
    }

    NavBar.prototype = new MySiteElement();

    return NavBar;
};
```